# Add javascript 'for' loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to prevent users to enter **Space** key in `input[type='text']` when it is empty. And if its not after entering **Space** key the value of `input[type='text']` should be grabbed and put it in a `span` tag. Now i want to assign a `for-loop` to do the second part(I mean put `value` in `span`) only *five times*. And when **5** `span` already exist.Don't do this any more. where should I add my `for-loops`?
here is my code:

```
$(function() 
   {
        $("#tags-selected").on('keypress', function(e) 
        {
                var tags_selected=$("#tags-selected").val();    
                if(e.which === 32)
                {
                    if(!this.value.length)
                        e.preventDefault();
                    else
                        $("<span class='suggested-tag'>"+tags_selected+"<span class='closee'>XX</span></span>").insertBefore("#tags-selected");
                        $("#tags-selected").val('');
                        $(".tags-review").fadeOut(300);

                } 

        });
    });
```

Comment: Don't you think you need to use trim while checking this `!this.value.length`, like this `!this.value.trim().length`, otherwise it will count blank space and will never satisfy your first condition?

Comment: it's your responsibility to check answers on your each question and mark and up-vote the correct answer.Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to add loop for that. Just check for the length of appended span elements with class suggested-tag. and only append new element if length is less than 5:

```
if($('span.suggested-tag').length < 5){
   $("<span class='suggested-tag'>"+tags_selected+"<span class='closee'>XX</span></span>").insertBefore("#tags-selected");
   $("#tags-selected").val('');
   $(".tags-review").fadeOut(300);
}
```